# How to incorporate customized wpf screens in Wix Solution

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-process, wix

We are developing a customized installer using Wix and Wpf. We have developed some screens using wpf and wish to integrate the same in Wix solution instead of using UI screens provided by Wix. Has anyone done this; Does WIX provides WPF dialogs or can we use our own custom dialogs (WPF Forms) in WIX solution. Any pointers for this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample in WiX that shows how to build a dll with DTF that wraps a WPF app as an embedded external ui handler but it's only a tiny beginning of what it would really take to do it correct.  I  keep meaning to work on a framework that would be skinable and extensible but I've yet to begin it.   I don't think anyone in the world has ever done it.  Visual Studio installer would be the closest.